How does work Vue v-model with update:modelValue and how to prevent it from default logic depending on modal
Can someone explain to me if v-model is:
:modelValue
update:modelValue
then what happen when v-model with update:modelValue used both.
So in my code I have this component:


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.4.8/vue.global.min.js"></script>
  <select-component
    v-model="selectedOrganization"
    :tooltip="selectedOrganization?.name"
    :getOptionLabel="organization => organization.name"
    :options="organizations"
    :searchable="true"
    :clearable="false"
    @update:modelValue="changeOrRedirectModal"
    @search="organizationSearchHandlerAsync">
  </select-component>



Under the hood this component uses v-select.
<v-select
        ref="select"
        :title="tooltip"
        class="select-component"
        :class="{ 'error-select': hasErrorsInternal }"
        :disabled="disabled"
        :style="width ? `width: ${width}` : null"
        v-bind="$attrs"
        :modelValue="modelValue"
        :options="options"
        :taggable="taggable"
        :multiple="multiple"
        :placeholder="placeholder"
        @search:focus="opened"
        @update:modelValue="onItemSelected"
        @search="(query, loadDelegate) => $emit('search', query, loadDelegate)">
        <div v-for="(s, name) in $slots" :key="name" :slot="name">
            <renderer :vnode="s" />
        </div>

        <div
            v-for="(f, name) in $slots"
            :key="name"
            :slot="name"
            slot-scope="props"
            :title="showItemsTooltips ? props.fullName : null">
            <renderer :vnode="f(props)" />
        </div>
    </v-select>

I need to prevent default logic on changing title on update:modelValue but only if on redirect model [another component that only has props to show and methods to either redirect to another organisation by url or do hide itself without redirecting] user presses accept button.
So using v-model leads to changing title no matter what button pressed.
How can I solve this issue? I don't think that changing v-model to :modelValue will fix this issue because there is no changing of value inside changeOrRedirectModal logic.

Under the hood this component uses v-select how? you also talk a lot about buttons and the statement but only if on redirect model user presses accept button is very confusing

Thanks for comment, going to add this code now

"another component that only has props to show and methods to either redirect to another organisation by url or do hide itself without redirecting] user presses accept button" - this isn't shown. It's unclear under which condition this is supposed to happen and in which component these props are available. "there is no changing of value inside changeOrRedirectModal logic" - it isn't shown either

v-model contains the current value (defautl or updated without control).
@update:modelValue it's like an event that trigger after v-model is updated.
I am not sure about what are you doing exaclty with others component and redirections on click (it seem to me that you need to check something before update the v-model value).
Did you try to use a computed value (:value="computedValue") instead v-model and an event change to manage the new value?

No, I haven't tryed computed but that's a great idea! Thank you, I'll try and I think that'll do
